# .jar file do not contain Main-Class attribute in manifest.mf

Tags: java, jar, manifest, mainclass

I am trying to run jar file through

```
java -jar jts.jar
```

but it is unable to run because it's Manifest.mf do not contain 'Main-Class' attribute, which is necessary for a jar file to run.

I am have same problem with 9-10 .jar files.
Help me with how to find those mainclass in jar files, there is no any directly defined mainclass in jar file.
How should I find the correct mainclass and how should I add it to manifest.mf

Comment: Please mention which IDE you are using.

Comment: you can use java -cp jst.jar YourMainClass to run

Comment: If there is no main class defined in the jar, they are probably not meant to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

On command line you can use following command to generate jar having existing manifest.

```
jar cvfm MyJarName.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

Refer this [page](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) for more details.

Alternatively, if you are using eclipse. Please follow steps mentioned [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-37.htm) to  export jar.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your Main-Class attribute on the last line of your manifest.txt, it vanishes if you do not have a new line at the end. Very annoying, but always make sure you have a new line at the end of your manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

```
1. You can open the jar file with winzip or winrar. 
2. Open manifest file in notepad. 
3. Add main-class: ClassNameContianingMainMethod. 
4. Save the file and then run it
```